# Sum values from each row of an associative 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I want to sum the values in each row of my associative array of associative rows.

My input:

```
[
    "A" => ["AA" => 10],
    "B" => ["BA" => 5, "BB" => 1, "BC" => -2],
    "C" => ["CA" => 3, "CB" => 0]
]
```

Desired Result:

```
['A' => 10, 'B' => 4, 'C' => 3]
```

I've tried to do this with a `foreach()`, but the result is wrong.

Can someone demonstrate and explain how to do this?

Comment: The implementation of my advice from the dupe target for this asked question: [`var_export(array_map('array_sum', $arr));`](https://3v4l.org/5Qmmc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop thru your array and use `array_sum`

```
$arr = array(
    "A" => array
        (
            "AA" => 10,
        ),

    "B" => array
        (
            "BA" => 5,
            "BB" => 1,
            "BC" => -2
        ),

    "C" => array
        (
            "CA" => 3,
            "CB" => 0
        )
);

$result = array();
foreach( $arr as $key => $val ){
    $result[$key] = array_sum ( $val );
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will result to:

```
Array
(
    [A] => 10
    [B] => 4
    [C] => 3
)
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 1):

This should work for arrays like the one of your example:

```
 $arr = array(
    "A" => array
        (
            "AA" => 10,
        ),

    "B" => array
        (
            "BA" => 5,
            "BB" => 1,
            "BC" => -2
        ),

    "C" => array
        (
            "CA" => 3,
            "CB" => 0
        )
);
$res = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as  $number) {
            (!isset($res[$key])) ?
                $res[$key] = $number :
                $res[$key] += $number;
        }
    }



echo "<pre>";
print_r( $res );
echo "</pre>";
```

This is working without using an inbuilt function.

Answer (score 0):

**if you want sum column**

```
<?php
$array = array
    (
      "A"=>array
        (
"AA" => 10,
        ),
      "B"=>array
        (
            "BA" => 5,
            "BB" => 1,
            "BC" => -2
        ),
      "C"=>array
        (
            "CA" => 3,
            "CB" => 0
         )
        );

foreach ($array as $key=>$value)
{
$mehrdad[]=$key;
}
foreach ($mehrdad as $key1=>$value1)
{
    $arrays=$array[$value1];
foreach ($arrays as $key2=>$value2)
{

$mehrdadi[]=$key2;
}

}
$mehrdadend=array_unique($mehrdadi);
$mehrdadis = array();
foreach ($mehrdadend as $key3=>$value3)
{
$sum=array_sum(array_column($array, $value3));

$mehrdadis[$value3] = $sum;
}
print_r($mehrdadis);
?>
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [AA] => 10
    [BA] => 5
    [BB] => 1
    [BC] => -2
    [CA] => 3
    [CB] => 0
)
```